# Is there a way to have a constructor within an already existing constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following function that acts a base constructor:

```
function Foo() = {}
...
exports Foo
```

It's an empty constructor, and is used by other functions which I don't want to change. Also, `Foo` is only being exported from the file.

Now I need to create a different constructor perhaps within `Foo`.

The following is what I'd have with `enum` as a standalone constructor. But how do I make it a part of `Foo`?

```
function enum(data) {
    this.data = data
}

enum.prototype.getVal() { return this.data; }

var obj = new enum(5);
obj.getVal();
```

Comment: `make it a part of Foo` is unclear. You mean you want to create a new instance of something and attach it to an instance of `Foo`? Like `function Foo() { this.something = new enum(); }`

Comment: a part of `Foo` such that I don't have to explicitly instantiate `enum` since `Foo` is only being exported from the file

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean when you say `make it a part of Foo` - do you mean you want `Foo` to inherit from `enum`? What is the relationship between `Foo` and `enum` that you want to achieve? Should each instance of `Foo` hold an instance of `enum`? Should each `Foo` share an instance of `enum`? etc...

Comment: Holding an instance means it's a part of the object itself. What does sharing an instance refer to? technically `Foo` should somehow store or share an instance of `enum` but the way the utility functions are already written is pretty bad, and I want to do it without breaking or doing something super extra. But currently, `Foo` is an empty constructor, and then we have added different methods to it. One example being: `Foo.General = {}; Foo.General.SetValue = function(value) {}`...

Comment: You're confusing terms. `Foo` doesn't appear to be a constructor, it appears to be a namespace. How is it being used? Is there any file anywhere that calls `new Foo()`? I'd hazard a guess not based on how you're describing it.

Comment: the files importing using `require` like `var Foo = require(path)`, but no `new Foo()` isn't being used. But I don't see how `Foo` isn't a constructor.

Comment: Any function called with `new` is a constructor (has it's own "this" context). Can you provide an example of how you would like to use it (forget about how to implement it, just an example of how you see it being used).

Comment: I provided an example of how ideally i'd want to use `enum`. but that's a standalone constructor which has nothing to do with `Foo`. I mentioned the issue with this design is I can't access `enum` outside since it's not being exported from the file, but only `Foo` is

Answer (score 0):

Taking a completely wild guess from your commnets.

exporting from the file is of no real concern. If you're just using `Foo` as a namespace to "hang" functions off of you can do this:

Enum.js

```
// all constructors should be capitalized
function Enum() { }
Enum.prototype.whatever ...

exports Enum
```

Foo.js

```
const Enum = require('./Enum');

// it's unclear why `Foo` is even a function to be honest
function Foo() { }

Foo.Enum = Enum;

exports Foo
```

someOtherFile.js

```
const Foo = require('./Foo');

const myEnumInstance = new Foo.Enum();
```

Comment: So it only makes sense to have a different file with `Enum` constructor since it's not being exported from `Foo.js`, yes?

Comment: @kol - no, you could put the entire implementation of `Enum` right inside `Foo.js`. But, frankly speaking, files are free, keep your code clean and create a separate file (or folder) for each concern. Any particular reason why `Enum` has to be exported from `Foo.js`? Why can't files that want to use it just `require('./Enum')`?

Comment: Mainly cause it's not as big of an implementation to have its own file is what I'm thinking. It's got a couple of methods

Comment: Separate your concerns, I'd rather have 100 20 line files than one 2000 line file.